# Does the Riemann rearrangement theorem affect the Euler summation transform?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, convergence-acceleration

I was wondering if  the [Riemann rearrangement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) has an affect on the [Euler summation transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_summation), since, when applying it to a conditionally convergent series, the rearrangement of terms may affect the value to which the series converges to.

On the other hand, the Euler sum is supposed to, if convergent, be equal to the original series.

So... does it, or does it not affect the value it converges too?

Comment: It seems clear from the description of the Euler summation transform that it does not affect the value of a conditionally convergent series. Perhaps your real question is "why is that so?".

Comment: @GregMartin Perhaps so, as it is not immediately clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [1,Theorem 2.26]:

> **Theorem.** The Euler summation method $(E,q)$ (for $q>0$) is *regular*. That is, $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} s$ implies $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{(E,q)} s$.

Note that this directly implies the following:

- If the series $\sum_n a_n$ is absolutely convergent, then its Eulerian sum (when it exists) will be the same value.
- If the series $\sum_n a_n$ is conditionally convergent, then its Eulerian sum (when it exists) will be the same value.

and in particular:

- Fix $\ell\in[-\infty,\infty]$. If the series $\sum_n a_n$ is conditionally convergent, there exists a rearrangement $\sum_n a_{\sigma(n)}$ converging to $\ell$, by the Riemann rearrangement theorem. Then the Eulerian sum (when it exists) of $\sum_n a_{\sigma(n)}$ will be $\ell$.

There is no contradiction: if you apply the Eulerian summation method to the conditionally convergent series $(a_n)_n$, you will get the same limit in the Eulerian sense. If you apply the Eulerian summation method to the (different) conditionally convergent series $(a_{\sigma(n)})_n$, you will get another limit than before in the Eulerian sense, because you are not considering the same series anymore in the first place.

---

[1] Shawyer, Bruce; Watson, Bruce (1994). *Borel's Methods of Summability: Theory and Applications.* Oxford University Press. ISBN 0-19-853585-6